# Why does my C# console application magically halt but resume upon pressing a key?

Tags: c#, console-application, user-input

I am developping a C# console application that occasionally shows a very strange behavior. The basic design is this:

1. Load a bunch of urls from a SQLite database
2. Try downloading the files at the urls using an httpRequest
3. Store the contents locally on disk
4. Log the success of that operation in the database

Throughout this operation messages are occasionally (like one for each file) written to the console. I **never** ask for user input in the application's code. Now comes the strange part: The application **halts from time to time, but resumes normally when I press a key** - just as if I did code a request for user input.

Since (unfortunately) the problem happens very rarely (I've only seen it two or three times) I haven't been able to reproduce it while running the program in VS2012's debugger as of now. Any alternative ideas on how to track it done would be appreciated.

Comment: This happens because you click the mouse pointer in the middle of the console, and drag it a slight bit, putting it in select mode. Look at the screen the next time it happens, you should see a spot with selection cursor.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that possibility. I can indeed reproduce that behaviour.